# flex regex not matching properly

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

In my tokenizer (.lex) file I want to match the following pattern :

```
AaBC12/awD41/dfs21 etc...
```

I've written this rule

```
[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*[[/]+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*]* 
{lline = cpflineno;cpflval.str = strdup(cpftext);return K_IDENTIFIER;}
```

This rule seems correct to me but if i have an input like this :

```
TOP/MD1 
TOP/MD2
TOP/MD2/D/E
```

My output is

```
TOP/MD1
TOP/MD2
TOP/MD2
/D/E
```

instead of

```
TOP/MD1
TOP/MD2
TOP/MD2/D/E
```

Could you tell me where my rule fails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*([/]+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)*
```

Replaced []  with () where you mean a group.

Note that it will match `foo////bar`, if you don't want that remove the second `+` (and the first `+` for that matter too, it's useless in this case).

Comment: That was obvious. I thought[] worked the same. I must be tired, thank you ;)